# Using the erase-remove idiom for 2D or 3D vectors

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

When I try using `vector.erase()` for a 2D vector inside a loop, I get a segmentation fault. Here's the code:

```
vector<vector<int> > fault;
...
...
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<fault.size(); j++)
    {
        if(pointer[i].val == fault[j][0])
            fault.erase(fault.begin() + j); //ERROR HERE!
    }
}
```

Is it because the size of the vector fault changes? Can I use the erase-remove idiom here instead? If so, how would I do it? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see anything here that should cause a problem, unless the `pointer` array is less than 10 elements.  (Note that when you erase element `j` from fault, you next loop iteration will skip the element that was moved down to replace the one removed.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! `Pointer` always has 10 elements. I tried debugging the error, and what I noticed was that fault.erase() enters some function in `vector.h` and doesn't exit.

Comment: You have to provide a minimal example, as it stands, your question is considered off-topic. Please read the guidelines, they also give a rationale why those are the rules. That said, it is easier and often more performant to copy those elements you want to keep to a new vector (reserving enough space up front) and then swap with the former one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can't cause a segmentation fault on the line you mention.

It is probably the if-statement that causes the segmentation fault. Either because `pointer` doesn't contain 10 valid elements or because `fault` doesn't have an element 0 (zero) in all the vectors it contains.

You could try to add this check:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<fault.size(); j++)
    {
        if (fault[j].size() > 0)
        {
            if(pointer[i].val == fault[j][0])
                fault.erase(fault.begin() + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, your logic seems wrong as you don't test all elements in the vector, i.e. when you erase one element the test will be skipped for the next element. Maybe you would need this instead:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<fault.size(); )
    {
        if((fault[j].size()>0) && (pointer[i].val == fault[j][0]))
        {
            fault.erase(fault.begin() + j);
        }
        else
        {
           // Only increment when no erase is done
           j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very new to C++, and this is helping me learn a lot. Out of curiosity, is it possible to use the erase-remove idiom for multidimensional vectors? I looked online, but didn't find any examples.